# VIM script NERDTree-<CR> remapping on condition

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, nerdtree

I am looking for a way to map NERDTree-<CR> on some condition.
If current window is empty, NERDTree-<CR> is mapped to NERDTree-o. If it is not, mapped to NERDTree-t.

I am a beginner of vimscript, so it is hard to find how to do it.
I tried to make a function like below and the function to be called on 'NERDTreeCustomArgsOpen', but couldn't make it.

```
" Couldn't make 'IsBufferModifiable' function
" and mapping 'MyNERDTree_CR' to 'NERDTreeCustomOpenArgs'

function! IsBufferModifiable(numBuffer)

function! IsBufferEmpty(numBuffer)
  return bufname(a:numBuffer) == ''
endfunction

function! IsModifiableBufferEmpty()
  let emptyModifiableBuffers = filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'IsBufferModifiable(v:val) && IsBufferEmpty(v:val)')

  if len(emptyModifiableBuffers) == 0
    return 1
  else
    return 0
endfunction

function! MyNERDTree_CR()
  if IsModifiableBufferEmpty()
    call feedkeys('o')
  else
    call feedkeys('t')
endfunction

" Not sure it works or not
let NERDTreeCustomOpenArgs = {'file':{'where':'MyNERDTree_CR', 'reuse':'all', 'keepopen':1, 'stay':1}}
```

Is there any way to make them work?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's intended but `IsBufferModifiable()` has no body and no closing `endfunction`.

Comment: @romainl Yes, you are right. I left it blank because I couldn't complete it as I said in comment on top

Answer (score 0):

Checking if a given buffer is modifiable is usually done by checking the value of the buffer-local `:help 'modifiable'` option:

```
function! IsBufferModifiable(numBuffer)
    return getbufvar(a:numBuffer, '&modifiable')
endfunction
```

See `:help getbufvar()`.